# How to add Ads for my android app using eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I am trying to add ads to my app but I don't know how I followed the instructions from this site:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html

I did step 1 and 2 in the getting started column, I imported the google-play-services_libs 
to my workspace then I referenced it in my app and I added this code in my mainfest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I opened the sample ad and copied this code to my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/>
```

but I am getting this error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.StarSurge.khwallpaper"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Java:

```
private AdView adView;

  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "-omitted-";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.adBanner);
    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("-omitted-")
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

so do you know how to fix this problem and can you tell me what should i write in the java to make in work thanks

Comment: If you have the old admob sdk as well as Google Play services then remove the old admob sdk from your libs folder and clean your project

Comment: @ozi I don't have the old admob in my lib folder

Comment: post your logcat console

Comment: you declared in xml for adview right.then why you are creating custom adview once again? @user3896367

Answer (score 0):

Whether you added this in manifest?

```
         <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

in java file:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads..comment for real app when launching
    // .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     //.addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198") //test this in emulator
            .build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```